# How to keep the docker container up and running?

Tags: docker

Here is my simple docker file

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 4000
```

now when I run it using the following command

```
sudo docker run --name hello dockerfile
```

and do `docker ps -a` it shows the status as exited. I just want to keep this container up and running so I can ssh into this container and probably transfer files and so on. It looks like containers are mainly used to run servers am I correct?

Answer (score 5):

you can at least keep your container up with something like `docker run -d hello sleep infinity` but as said by René M, you should put in your Dockerfile something to do in your CMD or ENTRYPOINT, see the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

and

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: In my experience, this, weirdly, does not guarantee infinite lifetime. The container will not be running after reboot (and it should).

Comment: Does your container have as restart policy "always" ?

Answer (score 4):

That is realy simple. 
Because your container is running nothing that last long. What happens is, that this container starts, has nothing to do and stops.

What you can do is:

1. Run the container in interactive mode with attached tty. This way your console enters the container after it's start, and let him run a tty, which is something to do and prevends the container from stopping. Then you can work inside this container, like installing an application. Doing this your work will be lost after stoping the container. But you can run docker commit on that container, which makes your changes persistent.

> docker run -i -t --name hello dockerfile

2. Enhance your dockerfile with something usefull. Like copying an application into the container and provide a CMD command to run, when the container starts.
   After this the container will last as long as your CMD command runs. If the command is a server or deamon application, the container will last for ever and will only stop when you stop him.